# WebGL works on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I have Lenovo laptop with a GeForce GT 755M/PCIe/SSE2 running Fedora 21 with Bumblebee installed.

I have tried multiple things to make WebGL work on Google Chrome, however nothing worked.

The weired thing though, is that the WebGL works on Firefox on the same computer.

When running chrome via `primusrun /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` I get the following messages:

```
[16014:16014:0528/154015:ERROR:url_pattern_set.cc(240)] Invalid url pattern: chrome://print/*
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[10:10:0528/154017:ERROR:resource_request_policy.cc(57)] Denying load of chrome-extension://apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf/page_embed_script.js from hosted app.
[10:10:0528/154018:ERROR:resource_request_policy.cc(57)] Denying load of chrome-extension://apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf/page_embed_script.js from hosted app.
[16014:16014:0528/154018:ERROR:display_info_provider_aura.cc(30)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::DisplayInfoProviderAura::UpdateDisplayUnitInfoForPlatform(const gfx::Display &, extensions::core_api::system_display::DisplayUnitInfo *)
[3,781924864:18:40:18.176817] Native Client module will be loaded at base address 0x00004c2f00000000
[16014:16014:0528/154022:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(164)] Could not send GpuCommandBufferMsg_Initialize
[16014:16014:0528/154022:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(209)] CommandBufferProxy::Initialize failed.
[16014:16014:0528/154022:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(226)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
[57:87:0528/154022:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(164)] Could not send GpuCommandBufferMsg_Initialize.
[125:136:0528/154022:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(164)] Could not send GpuCommandBufferMsg_Initialize.
[57:87:0528/154022:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(209)] CommandBufferProxy::Initialize failed.
[125:136:0528/154022:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(209)] CommandBufferProxy::Initialize failed.
[57:87:0528/154022:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(226)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
[125:136:0528/154022:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(226)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
[118:133:0528/154022:ERROR:gpu_channel_host.cc(175)] GpuChannelHost::CreateViewCommandBuffer failed.
[118:133:0528/154022:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(226)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[16014:16014:0528/154022:ERROR:gpu_channel_host.cc(222)] Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateOffscreenCommandBuffer.
[16014:16014:0528/154022:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(226)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(11748)]     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6570)]     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(11748)]     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6570)]     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(11748)]     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6570)]     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
[57:87:0528/154023:ERROR:gpu_channel_host.cc(175)] GpuChannelHost::CreateViewCommandBuffer failed.
[57:87:0528/154023:ERROR:webgraphicscontext3d_command_buffer_impl.cc(226)] Failed to initialize command buffer.
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[16014:16053:0528/154023:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(146)] Failed to create channel.
[16014:16388:0528/154028:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(243)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[10:10:0528/154031:ERROR:resource_request_policy.cc(57)] Denying load of chrome-extension://apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf/page_embed_script.js from hosted app.
```

The page `chrome://gpu` also shows:

```
GpuProcessHostUIShim: The GPU process crashed!
GpuProcessHostUIShim: The GPU process crashed!
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(11748)] :     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6570)] :     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(11748)] :     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6570)] :     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(11748)] :     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[16342:16342:0528/184023:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(6570)] :     [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:D05C467B47380000]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
GpuProcessHostUIShim: The GPU process crashed!
WARNING: Hardware acceleration is unavailable.
```